# Creating a Temp Dir in Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a temporary directory in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617414/create-a-temporary-directory-in-java)

I have a test for a create DB method and I need a temp directory to put it in. The directory will be removed after the test is done. I tried using `File.createTempFile()`, like so:

```
tempDir = File.createTempFile("install", "dir");
tempDir.mkdir();
```

But `tempDir` is already exists as a file. How do I create a temp directory as opposed to a file?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617414/create-a-temporary-directory-in-java