# deleting folder from java

Tags: java, file, directory

In Java, I want to delete all the contents that are present in a folder which includes files and folders.

```
public void startDeleting(String path) {
        List<String> filesList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> folderList = new ArrayList<String>();
        fetchCompleteList(filesList, folderList, path);
        for(String filePath : filesList) {
            File tempFile = new File(filePath);
            tempFile.delete();
        }
        for(String filePath : folderList) {
            File tempFile = new File(filePath);
            tempFile.delete();
        }
    }

private void fetchCompleteList(List<String> filesList, 
    List<String> folderList, String path) {
    File file = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFile = file.listFiles();
    for(File tempFile : listOfFile) {
        if(tempFile.isDirectory()) {
            folderList.add(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
            fetchCompleteList(filesList, 
                folderList, tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
        } else {
            filesList.add(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }

    }

}
```

This code does not work, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

If you use [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io) it's a one-liner:

```
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(dir);
```

See [FileUtils.deleteDirectory()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io///apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#deleteDirectory%28java.io.File%29)

---

<s>[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries) used to support similar functionality:</s>

```
Files.deleteRecursively(dir);
```

This has been removed from Guava several releases ago.

---

While the above version is very simple, it is also pretty dangerous, as it makes a lot of assumptions without telling you. So while it may be safe in most cases, I prefer the "official way" to do it (since Java 7):

```
public static void deleteFileOrFolder(final Path path) throws IOException {
  Files.walkFileTree(path, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>(){
    @Override public FileVisitResult visitFile(final Path file, final BasicFileAttributes attrs)
      throws IOException {
      Files.delete(file);
      return CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(final Path file, final IOException e) {
      return handleException(e);
    }

    private FileVisitResult handleException(final IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace(); // replace with more robust error handling
      return TERMINATE;
    }

    @Override public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(final Path dir, final IOException e)
      throws IOException {
      if(e!=null)return handleException(e);
      Files.delete(dir);
      return CONTINUE;
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: What are CONTINUE and TERMINATE? Should I import them from somewhere?

Comment: @bikashg enum constants inside java.nio.file.FileVisitResult. Most IDEs should be smart enough to suggest importing the enum type.

Comment: For those whose IDE is not smart enough (like mine), add this import declaration at the begin of the file manually: `import static java.nio.file.FileVisitResult.*;`

Comment: So you just crossed out the one-line solution in favor of 25-line solution? Wow..

Comment: @Vistritium you are still free to use the FileUtils version. Only it's rather unsafe, as it makes some assumptions that may or may not be true. File systems are complicated

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd what are the unsafe assumptions that Guava and FileUtils make?

Comment: @Jelaby it seems that only Java 7 introduced the proper tools to reliably detect symbolic links, and the Guava people didn't want to introduce a hard dependency to Java 7. See https://github.com/google/guava/issues/693. Dunno about apache commons

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Thanks. In FileUtils 2.5 (and maybe earlier), `FileUtils.deleteDirectory` does detect symlinks using different mechanisms depending on the OS and JRE (using the proper mechanisms in Java 7 and by messing with 1File.getCanonicalFile()` in earlier versions). (I [RTFS](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/src-html/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#line.1568)'d )

Answer (score 84):

I have something like this :

```
public static boolean deleteDirectory(File directory) {
    if(directory.exists()){
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        if(null!=files){
            for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
                if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
                    deleteDirectory(files[i]);
                }
                else {
                    files[i].delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return(directory.delete());
}
```

Comment: same algorithm but just a litle shorter

Comment: This is probably the ugliest formatted code I've ever seen, but the best answer to the question IMHO.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) 
{ 
  if (dir.isDirectory()) 
  { 
    String[] children = dir.list(); 
    for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++)
      return deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i])); 
  }  
  // The directory is now empty or this is a file so delete it 
  return dir.delete(); 
}
```

Comment: Messy code. Try cleaning it up a little.

Comment: Improved it a bit.

Comment: I don't think this would work. The return statement inside of the for loop would keep you from recursing to all children after the first was deleted.

Answer (score 6):

It could be problem with nested folders. Your code deletes the folders in the order they were found, which is top-down, which does not work. It might work if you reverse the folder list first.

But I would recommend you just use a library like Commons IO for this.

Answer (score 6):

I found this piece of code more understadable and working:

```
public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return dir.delete(); // The directory is empty now and can be deleted.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the [FileUtils.deleteDirectory()](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#deleteDirectory(java.io.File)) method can help to simplify the process of deleting directory and everything below it recursively.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779519/delete-files-recursively-in-java) question

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a method for this sometime back. It deletes the specified directory and returns true if the directory deletion was successful.

```
/**
 * Delets a dir recursively deleting anything inside it.
 * @param dir The dir to delete
 * @return true if the dir was successfully deleted
 */
public static boolean deleteDirectory(File dir) {
    if(! dir.exists() || !dir.isDirectory())    {
        return false;
    }

    String[] files = dir.list();
    for(int i = 0, len = files.length; i < len; i++)    {
        File f = new File(dir, files[i]);
        if(f.isDirectory()) {
            deleteDirectory(f);
        }else   {
            f.delete();
        }
    }
    return dir.delete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're storing all (sub-) files and folder recursively in a list, but with your current code you store the parent folder *before* you store the children. And so you try to delete the folder before it is empty. Try this code:

```
   if(tempFile.isDirectory()) {
        // children first
        fetchCompleteList(filesList, folderList, tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
        // parent folder last
        folderList.add(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc for [File.delete()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29)

> public boolean delete()
>
> Deletes the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname. If this pathname >denotes a directory, then the directory must be empty in order to be deleted.

So a folder has to be empty or deleting it will fail. Your code currently fills the folder list with the top most folder first, followed by its sub folders. Since you iterrate through the list in the same way it will try to delete the top most folder before deleting its subfolders, this will fail.

Changing these line

```
    for(String filePath : folderList) {
        File tempFile = new File(filePath);
        tempFile.delete();
    }
```

to this

```
    for(int i = folderList.size()-1;i>=0;i--) {
        File tempFile = new File(folderList.get(i));
        tempFile.delete();
    }
```

should cause your code to delete the sub folders first.

The delete operation also returns false when it fails, so you can check this value to do some error handling if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You should delete the file in the folder first , then the folder.This way you will recursively call the method.

Answer (score -1):

It will delete a folder recursively

```
public static void folderdel(String path){
    File f= new File(path);
    if(f.exists()){
        String[] list= f.list();
        if(list.length==0){
            if(f.delete()){
                System.out.println("folder deleted");
                return;
            }
        }
        else {
            for(int i=0; i<list.length ;i++){
                File f1= new File(path+"\\"+list[i]);
                if(f1.isFile()&& f1.exists()){
                    f1.delete();
                }
                if(f1.isDirectory()){
                    folderdel(""+f1);
                }
            }
            folderdel(path);
        }
    }
}
```