# Deleting files using a .jar

Tags: java, file, jar, delete-file

I have a .jar file called install.jar, which copies various file types to %appdata%/folder/abc/

What I need is a way to delete the files, either with the same jar or a new one, so I can reset the application for an update. I have looked on SO as well as google, and have found no answer.

If java doesn't let you delete folders, I need a way to delete all files inside of a folder, or at the very least, rename the folder.

Comment: You mean you haven't found anything on SO that explains how to delete a folder? http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=[java]%20%2bdelete%20%2bfolder

Comment: possible duplicate of [deleting folder from java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775694/deleting-folder-from-java)

Comment: If this is an application self-updater under windows then the file-locking of windows os may get in the way unless you stop the process first and ensure the updater jar is in a separate unrelated folder... Otherwise this question is a duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Deletes all files and subdirectories under dir.
// Returns true if all deletions were successful.
// If a deletion fails, the method stops attempting to delete and returns false.
public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // The directory is now empty so delete it
    return dir.delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could locate some useful information in this link. Which was previously asked.

Visit < [Is there a quick way to delete a file from a Jar / war without having to extract the jar and recreate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520822/is-there-a-quick-way-to-delete-a-file-from-a-jar-war-without-having-to-extract)>

Comment: I am not trying to delete files from a jar, but use a jar to delete external files.