# Files deleting issue

Tags: java, file

I have this code, which must remove files from the directory and the directory itself:

```
private static void removeTempFiles(File dir){
        if(!dir.exists())
            return;
        if(dir.isDirectory()){
            for(File f : dir.listFiles())
                removeTempFiles(f);
            dir.delete();
        }
        else {
            dir.delete();
        }
    }
```

but executing this code don't remove all the files. From time to time it removes all files with the folder or removes only a few files

**UPD:**
here is my creating file code:

```
 File tempFolder = new File(tempPath);
    tempFolder.mkdir();
    tempFolder.mkdirs();    
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new            FileOutputStream(tempPath+"/"+fileName);    
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOut, "windows-1251");
            try{
                osw.write(file64);
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
osw.close();
                fileOut.close();
            }
```

Comment: Probably permissions..

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775694/deleting-folder-from-java

Comment: You mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779519/delete-files-recursively-in-java ?

Comment: @fxm and that too :)

Comment: You may want to check the value returned by `delete()` and log it if it returns false.

Comment: @KorayTugay everything allright about permissions. and, as you see above it removes files from time to time

Comment: @nafas thesolution descrybed there drops exception "unable to delete file"

Comment: @NikitinMikhail alright mate, I think I know what the problem is, answer these question: r those files are used from external processes? if so, then they've been locked by those. are they use internally? if so u haven't closed the buffers

Comment: @nafas look. I've added some code. as for using them in other process - nope

Comment: Which OS does this happen under?

Comment: @NikitinMikhail if the behaviour is random, try to add some waiting on ur program.

Comment: @nafas imagine that this app will create and remove hundreds of files. what can heppen if I add waiting

Comment: @NikitinMikhail creating and deleting is risky. its not only about java. there are so many things in different levels can go wrong. if you have speed issue, try to create files concurrently  but add wait after creating and deleting each file

Comment: @nafas wait drops an exception 'java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
 at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)'. I don't need treads

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, it's normal that file deletion does not always succeed, because files can be locked by various services running on the system (antivirus, search indexing etc.). You need to add a retry loop around every file deletion call.

Comment: u mean do it until file.delete is true?

Comment: Usually you don't want to make an infinite number of retries. 10 attempts is usually OK.

Comment: @I've just create a loop until file.delete is true and it is still running. much more then 10 attempts

Comment: Then the file is actually locked by some other process. You can use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to check which process has opened the file.

Comment: there are no processes using this file when my app is not running. and when the app is running, I mean when the deleting loop is executing some 'non-existent process' is using it, which, i guess is the app itself

Comment: and what is interesting that only one of two created at one time files can't be removed.