# Can't Delete local File - Error "Is a Directory"

Tags: java, android, file, android-edittext

I have searched the vast Internet with no success. I am writing a file and then trying to delete it. My code has some commented out statements where I have tested it writing a file with contents both from a simple string, this works. However, when I try to make it create a file from an EditText (casted to a String) it has an error. I don't understand.

Someone please help me with this issue.

When I press the delete button, this error comes up:

```
04-14 11:40:38.086  24584-24584/com.test.dev.write_delete_local_file E/Exception﹕ File write failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.test.dev.write_delete_local_file/files: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
```

MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
    editContent = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.contentEdit);
    btnWrite = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnWrite);
    btnDelete = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

    fileContents = (String) editContent.getText().toString();
    fileName = (String) editName.getText().toString();

    btnWrite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            writeFile(fileName, fileContents);
        }

    });

    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            deleteTheFile(fileName);
        }

    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void writeFile(String name, String data) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        //OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("test.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(data);
        //outputStreamWriter.write("abcdefghijklmnop");
        outputStreamWriter.close();

        Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), (CharSequence) this.getFilesDir().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
}

public void deleteTheFile(String name){
    File chosenFile = context.getFileStreamPath(name);
    //File chosenFile = this.getFileStreamPath("test.txt");
    boolean fileDeleted = chosenFile.delete();
    if (fileDeleted) {
        Log.d(TAG, name + " was deleted");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, name + " was not deleted");
    }

}
```

Comment: This looks similar to this post. 

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775694/deleting-folder-from-java

Comment: I looked through that post and used the "deleteDirectory()" function suggested, however is there anyway I can check for sure that the file was deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because your file name is initialized in `onCreate` method, so in case if your `editText` doesn't have text in `XML` layout definition, `fileName` will be empty.

You should invoke `(String) editName.getText().toString()` in `btnDelete` click listener. Or set text change listener for `editText` and update `fileName` field every time when text changes.

Comment: I've added that and it seems to work, but not sure if it works.    I noticed that I need a way to verify whether the file was created or not. Thus I've added a read file to my code, but it doesn't seem to work.  :S

Comment: @Pyroclasm, if you've written something to file, then it was created successfully.