# How to delete the directory through java?

Tags: java

I am creating folder within a folder from java. Whenever the data loads, the directory should be reloaded with the new data.
My code is:

```
String ResultPath = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Desktop\\Report";
new File(ResultPath).mkdir();
new File(ResultPath + "\\images").mkdir();
```

I have used :

```
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(ResultPath));
```

in the if else loop to execute the same, but it is not displaying the desired output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [deleting folder from java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775694/deleting-folder-from-java)

Comment: What is the "desired output"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete directories recursively in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779519/delete-directories-recursively-in-java)

Comment: @nbro _Whenever the data loads, the directory should be reloaded with the new data_

Comment: @bub Reloading and deleting are different things. What does "whenever the data loads" actually mean? Which data?

Comment: @nbro I think she means when she reads from the directory after creating the  directory...but you are right, it is not 100% clear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you actually meant but to delete a directory using Java 8 API :

```
if (Files.exists(path, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
  Files.walk(path)
       .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
       .map(Path::toFile)
       .forEach(File::delete);
}
```

Do not forget to put the `LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS` option to not follow symbolic links as this can be dangerous.