# Delete a folder on SD card

Tags: android, sd-card

I tried `File.delete()` but it doesn't work. **How to delete a directory on SD card?**

I'm working on Android 2.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a whole folder and content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943629/how-to-delete-a-whole-folder-and-content)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You have to have all the directory empty before deleting the directory itself, see [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0483.html)

In Android, you should have the proper permissions as well - `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in your manifest.

**EDIT: for convenience I copied the code here, but it is still from the link above**

```
public static boolean deleteDirectory(File path) {
    if( path.exists() ) {
      File[] files = path.listFiles();
      if (files == null) {
          return true;
      }
      for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
         if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
           deleteDirectory(files[i]);
         }
         else {
           files[i].delete();
         }
      }
    }
    return( path.delete() );
  }
```

Comment: I tried removing files in the folder, but Logcat is showing `unable to unlink '/geo1.xml': Read-only file system (errno=30)`. I've added the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in manifest.

Comment: I think `/geo1.xml` is not in SD card, but in root (`/`). are you sure you are pointing to the correct file?

Comment: No, `/geo.xml` was in the folder I was trying to remove, but I was missing something in the code. Its working fine now. Thanks. :)

Comment: You need to add a if (files != null) test around the for loop, or you'll throw an exception the first time the for loop is evaluated if files is null.

Comment: @ perfect,... perfect

Comment: Why do you return true if there are no files? That way the folder will not be deleted.

Comment: This can be improved by replacing `for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {` with `for (File file : files) {`. As well as replacing `files[i].delete();` with `boolean wasDeleted = file.delete();`.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16411911/2397275

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

in AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 1):

Directories must be empty before they will be deleted. You have to recursively empty and delete all directories in the tree:

```
boolean delete(File file) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        if (files != null)
            for (File f : files) delete(f);
    }
    return file.delete();
}
```

*Update:*

It seems like `file.isDirectory() == (file.listFiles() == null)`, but `file.listFiles()` logs "`fail readDirectory() errno=20`" when `file.isDirectory() == false`.

Answer (score 1):

it's worked fine for me, i hope it will work for you.

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"DirName"); 
if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            new File(dir, children[i]).delete();
        }
    }
```

Comment: dir.list can return null, therefore calling children.length in your loop without checking whether children is null or not can throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me:

```
Add in manifest-
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 

private boolean deleteDirectory(File path) {
        if( path.exists() ) {
            File[] files = path.listFiles();
            if (files == null) {
                return false;
            }
            for(File file : files) {
                if(file.isDirectory()) {
                    deleteDirectory(file);
                }
                else {
                file.delete();
                }
            }
        }
        return path.exists()?path.delete():false;
    }
```

Comment: Correct practice would be too replace `file.delete` with `boolean wasDeleted = file.delete();` and below that calling `if (wasDeleted) {Log.i("Deleted ", "successfully");}`. I also agree that it's better using a for each loop (`for(File file : files)`) instead of the accepted answer(`for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++)`).