# Android delete files folder from Internal Storage not working

Tags: android, delete-file

I'm trying to delete my files folder from Internal Storage, but the code which I'm using is not actually working. Any ideas why?

```
Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name = "/data/data/"+context.getPackageName()+"/files/";
                Log.e("","path : "+name);
                File myDir = new File(name);
                myDir.delete();
                boolean iff = myDir.delete();
                Log.e("","iff : "+iff);
            }
        });
```

The result which I get after button click :

```
11-17 13:09:58.869: E/(15952): path : /data/data/com.android.test/files/
11-17 13:09:58.869: E/(15952): iff : false
```

Comment: did you set appropriate permission in menifest ??

Comment: Look at my answer on your previous question.

Comment: just a reminder, debugging won't show the correct output! you actually need to run the code and see the results!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are deleting the file twice and only checking the return value of the second delete.

If a file does not exist and you call delete() on it you get "false" as result (file was not deleted because it did not exist).

Comment: In addition check for if file.exists();

Comment: I didn't notices that I'm deleting the file twice.Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

File.delete() will only delete empty directories.
You will need to (recursively) delete the directory's contents first. 
That has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5701623/466771).
(Since that's an SO answer I'm not copying and pasting that answer to here)