# Show issue while deleting directory

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delete a folder on SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701586/delete-a-folder-on-sd-card)

In my app i saved all my data using internal storage i.e file. So at the first instance by using the `ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());` class i get the directory path as `m_AllPageDirectoryPath = cw.getDir("AllPageFolder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` Inside this directory path i saved some file File as Page01, page02, Page03 and so on.

Again inside Page01 i saved some file like image01, image02...using the same concept `m_PageDirectoryPath = cw.getDir("Page01", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` Now on delete of m_AllPageDirectoryPath i want to delete all the file associate with it. I tried using this code but it doesn't work.

```
File file = new File(m_AllPageDirectoryPath.getPath()); 
file.delete();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code only works if your **directory is empty**.

If your directory includes Files and Sub Directories, then you have to **delete all files recursively**..

Try this code,

```
// Deletes all files and subdirectories under dir.
// Returns true if all deletions were successful.
// If a deletion fails, the method stops attempting to delete and returns false.
public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // The directory is now empty so delete it
    return dir.delete();
}
```

(Actually you have to search on internet before asking like this questions)

Comment: +1 nice concept of deleting all files first and the deleting dir

Comment: My directory folder structure is like this. MainDirectory->haveMoreTheOneSubdirectory->HaveMoreThenOneFile..so i want to delete particular subdirectory and its file

Comment: Above code deletes directory which you will given in parameter.