# How to delete all files in a particular path of sdcard？

Tags: android, sd-card

I want to delete all files in a particular path of sdcard. I use the below code:

```
private void readFile(File[] file) {
   for (int i = 0; file != null && i < file.length; i++) {
      // now i check if it is a file or filename extension 
      if (file[i].isFile() && file[i].getName().endsWith("txt")) {
         fileList.add(file[i].toString());
      } else if (file[i].isDirectory()) {// if it is a file,recursive scanning
         File[] newFileList = new File(file[i].getAbsolutePath()).listFiles();
         readFile(newFileList);
      }
   }
}
```

Now i set scanning path:

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
String res = "";
try {
fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
File[] files = new File(FILEPATH).listFiles();
readFile(files);
for (File file : files) {
Log.i("syso", "" + file);
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
int length = fin.available();
byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
fin.read(buffer);
res = EncodingUtils.getString(buffer, "UTF-8");
// System.out.println(res);
boolean isDelete = file.delete();
if (isDelete = true) {
System.out.println("Deleted successful！！");
} else {
System.out.println("Deleted fail！！");
}
```

I set creating and deleting file permission in SDCard

Comment: did you give uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission in android manifest?

Comment: Try [this][1] it might help to you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943629/android-how-to-delete-a-whole-folder-and-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code as I needed an application which deletes some files on my sdcard. On my phone your code is working. I only recognized that you use in the following line

```
if (isDelete = true) {
```

an assingment instead of a comparison operator. Therefore, I suppose the if statement will always evaluate to true and always prints that the delete was successful even if the deletion of a file failed. I think

```
if (isDelete == true) {
```

is what you wanted to write. As you did not say anything about your specific troubles with your code, I do not know how to help you besides testing your code.