# Delete files from a known folder

Tags: android, delete-file

I'm trying to delete all files that are exists in a known path.

I've used the next function to do so -

```
public void deleteAllImages(){
     Log.d(TAG, "ENTERD DELETED ALL IMAGES ");
    String path = "/data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir/";
    File directory = new File(path);


    if (directory.isDirectory()){
         Log.d(TAG, "ENTERED IF ");
         for (File child : directory.listFiles()){
             Log.d(TAG, "ENTERED FOR "+ child);
             child.delete();
         }
    }
}
```

But it seem that it never getting into the if statement - guess it mean that it doesn't treat directory as one. So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: are you sure the value of `path` is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the `path` is not correct. The `isDirectory()` will return `false` in the following cases:

- The path points to file (obviously), and not to directory.
- The path
  is invalid (i.e. there is no such file/directory exists).
- There is
  not enough permissions granted to your application to determine
  whether path points to directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if (dir.isDirectory()) {
    String[] children = dir.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        new File(dir, children[i]).delete();
    }
}
```

Check this : [Delete files from folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943629/android-how-to-delete-a-whole-folder-and-content)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
        String path = "/data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir/"; 
        File file = new File(path);
        if(file.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = file.listFiles();
            if(files != null && files.length > 0) {
              for (File file2 : files) {
                file2.delete();
              }
            }
        }
```