# Clear android application data programmatically

Tags: android, storage, android-memory

Manually I can do

```
Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> (choose my app) -> Clear data
```

How do I do this programmatically?

I need to delete all data, including those in shared preferences (, and variables).

Comment: instead of hardcoding `/data/data/com.example.applicationpackagename/.` how do I specify it? since according to @ChrisStratton I cannot use `getExternalFilesDir(null)`

Answer (score 0):

Everything in your application is stored here `/data/data/com.example.applicationpackagename/`.

Your application is run by a user which has R/W access on this directory.

You just need to remove every files in it.

For information : [Android - How to delete a whole folder and content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943629/android-how-to-delete-a-whole-folder-and-content)

Comment: Not quite true.  You **do not** have write access to all the files within that directory - for example, the libs/ folder which would contain jni libraries.  However I don't believe clearing application would normally remove that.  Also, you should not be assuming what the package's private directory will be, but rather discovering what it is on the particular device using the appropriate APIs.

Comment: thanks for the inputs. But, is the answer to use: `if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            new File(dir, children[i]).delete();
        }
    }` or is that incorrect according to @ChrisStratton ?

Comment: Well, you'd have to gracefully handle failure or proactively skip the folders you aren't allowed to delete.

Comment: that's fine than. Thank you. Will test and up you. Thanks.

Comment: The file that I am to pass in, is it the same as `getExternalFilesDir(null)`? If so then it's not removing my shared preferences. I need to remove them too in that one call. tagging @ChrisStratton

Comment: No.  That would be the External storage, while this is the private directory on the Internal storage.

Answer (score -2):

You could use  following code in which "packagename" could be your application package name like com.example.app1

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
```