# empty directory not deleting in android

Tags: android, file

Can anyone tell why this code is not working for deleting an empty directory even that path.exists() returns true but not performing delete operation..

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/directoryName");
    boolean isDeleted = deleteDirectory(file);
    System.out.println(isDeleted);
}

static public boolean deleteDirectory(File path) {
    if (path.exists()) {
        System.out.println("MainActivity.deleteDirectory()");
        File[] files = path.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                deleteDirectory(files[i]);
            } else {
                files[i].delete();
            }
        }
    }
    return (path.delete());
}
```

Comment: what's your problem... can you explain in telugu please

Comment: Please paste the log if you are getting any kind of error log in logcat.

Comment: You are trying to delete contents in "directoryName" folder. But your code cannot delete "directoryName" folder.

Comment: I found this function from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6425744/1739882.

Check if it works..

Comment: You are not deleting dirctory.

Comment: ohh, sorry but u r not deleting dir in proper way.

Comment: in that directory if any files or sub directories are available i want to delete that files first later i m deleting that directory...but it is not deleting any file or directory

Answer (score 2):

Change the sequence a bit to:

```
boolean deleteDirectory(File path) {
    if(path.exists()) {
        if (path.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = path.listFiles();
            for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
                deleteDirectory(files[i]);
            }
        }
        return path.delete();
    }

    return false;
}
```

And remember to declare permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```