# Delete cache files for a specific application

Tags: android

Inspired by [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6425744/2436175), I would like to delete a specific application's files (cache).
Here is the code:

```
       void DeleteRecursive() {
            String path="/sdcard/android/data/aaa.bb.cc/cache"
         File fileOrDirectory= new File(path);
        if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory())
            for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles())
                DeleteRecursive(child);

        fileOrDirectory.delete();
    }
```

But after deleting files when I go into the file manager, file still exists.
What is wrong?

Comment: do you have the right permissions?

Comment: Android is permission based. If your app doesn't have the right permission to delete/modify/create files. Check the return value of delete, it will definately be false.

Comment: @Antonio If you viewed the related question, you should have seen that the user is using the code from teedyay (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6425744/47351) The question is about why it does not delete.

Comment: ligi and Rvdk  Thank you very much for helping...i forget permisssions