# Android, clear app's data

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an android app in which I write information on some .dat files, I want to find a way to delete all the app's data of my Android app, writing some Java code. Anyone knows how to solve this problem ?

[AppData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hQM8.png)

Comment: Do yo wanna clear your app's data?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134103/clear-applications-data-programmatically) out.

Comment: Yes, I want to delete App's data as shown in the picture

Answer (score 0):

You have to find data folder of each application and remove it.

For example your application data is stored there: */data/data/com.example.applicationpackagename/*

Here is more information how to remove whole folder:
[How to delete a whole folder and content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943629/how-to-delete-a-whole-folder-and-content)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using shared presence than just run below code:

```
prefence.edit().clear().apply();
```