# android 10 delete folder

Tags: android, android-10.0

If I create a folder in Android 7/9, the location is:

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "FOLDER_NAME"

But in Android 10 I want to delete the old folder, how I can delete the folder?

I have tried 3 methods so far;

1.

```
File newFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "FOLDER_NAME");
newFile.delete();
```

2.

Get the folder list, then delete all files as shown in this thread:

[How to delete a whole folder and content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943629/how-to-delete-a-whole-folder-and-content)

3.

Using MediaStore way I can not find the folder.

```
String[] projection = null;

String selection;

String[] selectionArgs;

Cursor cursor = null;

projection = new String[]{ MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID, MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.TITLE};

selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + " like ?";

selectionArgs = new String[]{"%" + "FOLDER_NAME" + "/%"};

Uri external = null;

for (String volumeName : MediaStore.getExternalVolumeNames(context)) {

    external = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(volumeName);
    break;

}

cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"),
projection,
selection,
selectionArgs,
null);

if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {

Uri fileUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(external,      cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID)));

    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();

    resolver.delete(fileUri, null, null);

}
```

Is there any way I can delete the old folder in Android 10?

Comment: So what types of error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a file manager app for Android Q can do the job.

Otherwise use Storage Access Framework.

Take ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE  to let the user choose the parent of your directory.

With obtained write permissions for the parent you can now delete any child.

Answer (score 0):

If you have URI access to that folder, then you can delete it recursively (along with its children) with [Simple Storage](https://github.com/anggrayudi/SimpleStorage):

```kotlin
// We want to delete folder /storage/emulated/0/Video/Horror
val folder = DocumentFileCompat.fromSimplePath(context, basePath = "Video/Horror")
// Set childrenOnly to true if you want to delete its children only
val success = folder?.deleteRecursively(context, childrenOnly = false)
```