# How can I delete all files from or format an external SD card programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I have done done lots of googling and searching here on StackOverflow for an answer to my question. I have seen the **many** posts about a recursive file deletion method ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59372172/is-it-possible-to-format-secondary-sd-card-in-android-10), [this](http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.com/2014/10/android-clear-application-data-and.html), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943629/how-to-delete-a-whole-folder-and-content)), but none of these have worked for me. I am using this method to find my SD card (which is `/storage/0000-0000`).

```
private void wipeSDCards() {
    File storage = new File("/storage");
    File[] storageSubDirs = storage.listFiles();
    for (File storageSubDir : storageSubDirs) {
        try {
            boolean storageSubDirIsEmulated = Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated(storageSubDir);
            boolean storageSubDirIsRemovable = Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable(storageSubDir);

            if (!storageSubDirIsEmulated && storageSubDirIsRemovable) {
                deleteStuff(storageSubDir);
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            LoggingUtil.i(MyClass.class, String.format(Locale.US, "FAILED ON: %s", storageSubDir.getAbsolutePath()));
        }
    }
}

private void deleteStuff(File fileOrDirectory) {
    // things I have tried ....
}
```

To delete the files on the SD card I have tried:

```
File fileToDelete = new File('path.to.file');
fileToDelete.delete();
```

But that doesn't work. I have tried:

```
Files.delete(fileToDelete.toPath());
```

But that doesn't work. I have tried:

```
application.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
```

But that doesn't work either. I have placed this print statement just before all my deletion attempts:

```
Log.e("LOOK HERE: ", String.format(Locale.US, "Your Application %s delete this file (%s)", (fileOrDirectory.canWrite() ? "can" : "can NOT"), fileOrDirectory.getName()));
```

And have always gotten back `Your Application can NOT delete this file (path.to.file)`. It seems that I do not have the authorization to delete files on the SD card, even though I can through the Windows file browser.

So, is an application allowed to delete the contents of the SD card? If so, how does one go about doing this? How about a method to just format the SD card, I would take that as well.

Also, please don't ask "why do you want to do this" ... I just do.

Comment: Removable micro SD cards are no longer writable for normal apps.

Comment: Only in the app specific directory on the microi SD card you can write and delete.

Comment: You find the app specific directory on the micro SD card as the second item returned by getExternalFilesDirs(). (And then you know the path to the root of the card too).

Comment: You can format the card using Seetings of your Android device.

Comment: If you realley want to write and delete any content on the micro SD card then use Storage Access Framework.