# Java 8 Path Stream and FileSystemException (Too many open files)

Tags: java-8, nio

geniuses!

I'm practicing Java 8.

So if I do something like this:

```
Files.walk(Paths.get(corpusPathStr))
        .filter(path -> path.toFile().isFile())
        .forEach(path -> {
            try {
                Files.lines(path)
                        .forEach(...);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

I got FileSystemException error.

If I open a file under forEach, may too many files be opened?

Or are there other reasons causing FileSystemException (Too many open files)?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
try(Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(Paths.get(corpusPathStr))) {
    stream.filter(path -> Files.isRegularFile(path) && Files.isReadable(path))
          .flatMap(path -> {
                       try { return Files.lines(path); }
                       catch (IOException e) { throw new UncheckedIOException(e); }
                   })
          .forEach(...);
}
catch(UncheckedIOException ex) {
    throw ex.getCause();
}
```

The streams returned by `Files.walk` and `Files.lines` must be properly closed to release the resources, which you do by either, a `try(…)` construct or returning them in the mapping function of a `flatMap` operation.

Don’t use nested `forEach`s.

The `UncheckedIOException` might not only be thrown by our mapping function, but also the stream implementations. Translating it back to an `IOException` allows to treat them all equally.

Comment: What if Files.lines throw an exception while lining? Wouldn't that cause an opened stream to be never closed given that the stream will never be returned to the flatmap ?

Comment: To me it seems like to process all line in all files at once? Map all files to lines then process them all? Or does it process limes file by file?

Comment: @GyuHyeon Choi: streams are lazy, so this will process one file after another (unless you enable parallel processing, which would imply the possibility of processing one file per thread).

Comment: @Jean-François Savard: if an exception occurs before `Files.lines` returns, it is the responsibility of `Files.lines` to close the stream before propagating the exception to the caller. As you can see [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/nio/file/Files.java#3743), it will close the underlying `BufferedReader`, if an exception occurs during Stream construction, before rethrowing the exception.

Answer (score 7):

`Files::line` opens and reads the file in a lazy manner, i.e. `Stream<String>`. Since you're not closing any of your opened `Stream`s you're getting such an error.

So when you're done reading a file you should close its handle. Since the returned `Stream` is `AutoCloseable` you can and should use a try-with-resource block.

```
try (Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(Paths.get(""))) {
  walk.filter(Files::isRegularFile).forEach(path -> {
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
      lines.forEach(System.out::println);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  });
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```