# Is there a maximum of files that Java application can have open at one moment?

Tags: java, exception, intellij-idea, memory-management, file-io

I am writing a Java application that needs to work with many files open at the same time. I know how to get the maximum available memory for the files to be read, but is there such a thing as having too many files open, regardless of available memory?

I've seen questions about "to many open files" error, but reading the documentation, I am not able to reproduce the conditions and therefore not sure how to handle such an error/exception.

I've looked into java.io.File and java.nio.Files for such errors or exceptions. Of course looked for it online, especially on stackoverflow, and the search for similar questions did not return what I need.

```
public static int MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_FILES;

/* maximum file number inside a folder depends on the system */
/* maximum number of open files inside RAM ? */


//methods
public static long getAvailableMemory(){
    System.gc(); //clear as much as possible
    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
    long maxMemory = r.maxMemory(); //add case if this is greater than Long.max_value
    long totalMemory = r.totalMemory(); //add case if this is greater than Long.max_value
    long freeMemory = r.freeMemory();
    return maxMemory - (totalMemory-freeMemory);

}


public static long determineChunkSize(final long fileSize){

    return getAvailableMemory()/MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_FILES;
}
```

Comment: It's not up to Java to decide. It's the OS that will limit open files, if it wants to. You could try to query the OS for any limits, but it would be better not to write code that opens excessive files or tries to do something based on the (possible) limit. See for example [ulimit](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/ulimit.htm).

Comment: Can I get such a maximum, if any, from the application?

Comment: How many files were you thinking of opening?

Comment: That is what I do not know, I am actually working on external sorting and I need to determine maximum file size based on maximum available memory and some number of files. It has to work for -Xmx256m. While trying to determine that maximum number of files, I found on the net that people had "too many open files" error, trying to determine how not to allow such case to be unhandled.

Comment: Just keep opening them until you get the exception, then that's how many.

Comment: My application will be run on multiple systems, yet I currently can test it only on MacOS and Windows. I found [this](https://linux.101hacks.com/unix/java-too-many-open-files/) for Linux, and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067269/java-8-path-stream-and-filesystemexception-too-many-open-files) is similar to mine but it does not give me the answer

Comment: There is no single answer. Every system could be different. Every invocation could be different, because of `ulimit`. That's why you should rely on the exception rather than a constant.