# Delete files before creating new from temp using Java file method

Tags: java, xml, file-handling, tempdir

I have below code where i am trying to create new file in `temp` directory which is `xml` file and its working fine.

Now everytime i run the code, i want to delete the previous xml file from this `temp` directory before creating new xml file because of the size of the xml file is large and it might full my temp space. The xml file has certain naming convention `life__*.xml`. So it should delete all the `life__*.xml` files.

I am not sure if we can use `tempFile.deleteOnExit()` here or how to use that as i am quite new in java file handling and dont know what and where to make change in code:

```
*/
@Slf4j
public class InputConsumer implements Runnable {

    public static final String XML_SUFFIX = ".xml";

    private void processlifeZipFile() {        //check the number of line in xml input zip file processed
        final AtomicBoolean isInsideLeiRecord = new AtomicBoolean();
        isInsideLeiRecord.set(false);
        final StringBuilder currentLeiRecordXml = new StringBuilder();
        try (FileSystem zipFs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(jobRunner.getInputZipPath(), null);   //check the zip file
             Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(xmlFileFromLeiZipFile(zipFs))) {  //streaming the lines inside xml file
            AtomicInteger processedLinesCounter = new AtomicInteger();
            AtomicInteger currentLineNumber = new AtomicInteger();
            lines
                    .sequential()
                    .forEach(handleLineAndIncrementLineNumber(isInsideLeiRecord, currentLeiRecordXml, processedLinesCounter, currentLineNumber))
            ;
            log.info("{} lines of XML file inside life input ZIP file {} processed.", processedLinesCounter.get(), jobRunner.getInputZipPath() //number of lines processed in xml file
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Problem reading input file at " + jobRunner.getInputZipPath() + ".", e);
        }
    }
    private Path xmlFileFromLeiZipFile(FileSystem zipFs) {       //extracts the xml file from zip file
        log.info("Input file {} exists: {}", jobRunner.getInputZipPath(), Files.exists(jobRunner.getInputZipPath()));
        Path tmpXmlPath = createTmpXmlFile("life__" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        for (Path rootDir : zipFs.getRootDirectories()) {
            try (Stream<Path> files = treeAt(rootDir)) {
                log.info("Trying to extract life XML file from ZIP file into {}.", tmpXmlPath);
                final Path xmlFileInsideZip = files
                        .filter(isNotADir())
                        .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                        .findFirst()
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("No file found in LEI ZIP file."));
                log.info("Path to life XML file inside ZIP file: {}.", xmlFileInsideZip);
                return copyReplacing(xmlFileInsideZip, tmpXmlPath);
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("No file found in LEI ZIP file " + jobRunner.getInputZipPath() + ".");
    }
    

    private static Path createTmpXmlFile(final String prefix) {
        try {
            log.info("Creating temporary file {}{}", prefix, XML_SUFFIX);
            return Files.createTempFile(prefix, XML_SUFFIX);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not create tmp file at " + prefix + XML_SUFFIX + ". ", e);
        }
    }
    
    @NotNull
    private static Path copyReplacing(Path from, Path to) {
        requireNonNull(from, "Trying to copy from a path, which is null to path " + to + ".");   //trying to copy file where no xml file exist in root directory
        requireNonNull(to, "Trying to copy from path " + from + " to a path, which is null.");
        try {
            return Files.copy(from, to, REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot copy from " + from + " to " + to + ". ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: deleteOnExit only performs the delete when the JVM exits. Create a file object with the path, and call .delete() when you finished the copy. Then return the copy

Comment: can you please mentione the code for doing the same ..its really helpful as i was trying the same but not luck yet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Andrew, Please try the below code change done in method processlifeZipFile() and see if it works.

private void processlifeZipFile() {        //check the number of line in xml input zip file processed
        final AtomicBoolean isInsideLeiRecord = new AtomicBoolean();
        isInsideLeiRecord.set(false);
        final StringBuilder currentLeiRecordXml = new StringBuilder();
        Object jobRunner;
        try (FileSystem zipFs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(jobRunner.getInputZipPath(), null);   //check the zip file
                java.nio.file.Path tmpXMLFilePath = xmlFile`enter code here`FromLeiZipFile(zipFs); // Change
             Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(tmpXMLFilePath)) {  //streaming the lines inside xml file
            AtomicInteger processedLinesCounter = new AtomicInteger();
            AtomicInteger currentLineNumber = new AtomicInteger();
            lines
                    .sequential()
                    .forEach(handleLineAndIncrementLineNumber(isInsideLeiRecord, currentLeiRecordXml, processedLinesCounter, currentLineNumber))
            ;
            log.info("{} lines of XML file inside life input ZIP file {} processed.", processedLinesCounter.get(), jobRunner.getInputZipPath() //number of lines processed in xml file
            );
            Files.delete(tmpXMLFilePath); // change
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Problem reading input file at " + jobRunner.getInputZipPath() + ".", e);
        }
    }
```

EDIT ---->

I have created a new method to delete all other files except the new temp xml file.

```
void deleteXMLFiles(Path xmlPath) {
        try {
            final List<Path> pathsToDelete = Files.list(xmlPath.getParent()).sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList());
            for(Path path : pathsToDelete) {
                if (path.equals(xmlPath)) {
                    System.out.println("Skipping newly created XML file");
                    continue;
                }
                Files.delete(path);
                System.out.println("Deleting -> " + path.toString());
            }
        }catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Replace the line "Files.delete(tmpXMLFilePath); // change" with the call to the newly created method with tmpXMLFilePath as the parameter.

deleteXMLFiles(tmpXMLFilePath);

Refer this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47994874/13677537

EDIT 2 ---->

modified the method deleteXMLFiles() to check the file name pattern before deleting :

```
void deleteXMLFiles(Path xmlPath) {
        try {
            final List<Path> pathsToDelete = Files.list(xmlPath).sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList());
            for (Path path : pathsToDelete) {
                String xmlFileName = path.toString();
                if (Pattern.matches(".*life__.*.xml", xmlFileName)) {
                    Files.delete(path);
                    System.out.println("Deleting -> " + xmlFileName);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Modified the processlifeZipFile() method call to delete the temp XML files before creating the new one :

```
private void processlifeZipFile() {        //check the number of line in xml input zip file processed
        final AtomicBoolean isInsideLeiRecord = new AtomicBoolean();
        isInsideLeiRecord.set(false);
        final StringBuilder currentLeiRecordXml = new StringBuilder();
        
        // Delete the old temp XML Files before starting the processing
        deleteXMLFiles(Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));
        
        try (FileSystem zipFs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(jobRunner.getInputZipPath(), null);   //check the zip file
             Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(xmlFileFromLeiZipFile(zipFs))) {  //streaming the lines inside xml file
            AtomicInteger processedLinesCounter = new AtomicInteger();
            AtomicInteger currentLineNumber = new AtomicInteger();
            lines
                    .sequential()
                    .forEach(handleLineAndIncrementLineNumber(isInsideLeiRecord, currentLeiRecordXml, processedLinesCounter, currentLineNumber))
            ;
            log.info("{} lines of XML file inside life input ZIP file {} processed.", processedLinesCounter.get(), jobRunner.getInputZipPath() //number of lines processed in xml file
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Problem reading input file at " + jobRunner.getInputZipPath() + ".", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please replace the line "Files.delete(tmpXMLFilePath);" with the below line:      "log.info("Temp File Deleted : " + Files.deleteIfExists(tmpXMLFilePath));" and try.

Comment: its deleting the incorrect file actually which is getting created and not all the previous xml files

Comment: thanks i am checking now but one question because i want to delete only life__*.xml files because it has been created by this process and i think this logic will delete all *.xml files from tmp directory folder ?

Comment: i just tried ...its trying to delete all the other files from temp directory excluding the life__*.xml files

Comment: Check the changes given in the EDIT 2 section of the answer

Comment: it will be really helpful if you can help me here: i am using same code but want little bit different logic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62537379/file-createtempfile-method-not-working-in-java-and-getting-incompatible-type-err