# java FileUtils.delete() not deleting folder

Tags: java

Whats wrong with my code ? with reference with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779519/delete-directories-recursively-in-java)

the folder is not being deleted.

```
    File f = new File(directory+"\\OOO");
    if (f.exists())
    {            
        System.out.println(f);

        FileUtils.delete(f);

        f.delete();
    //  f.mkdir();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("created");

        //f.mkdir();
    }
```

[image: Method defined]

Comment: you should use deleteDirectory instead of delete method

Comment: How is `System.out.println("d");` related to the question  ?  Check if `f` is a valid folder by `f.isDirectory()`

Comment: @VugarSuleymanov it didnt work please check my edit

Comment: Please fistly check that which library you use. Check that you use [apache.commons.io](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) library.

Comment: Your FileUtils import statement is using the wrong library. Also, you should pick an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) does not contain any method named `delete()`;

You should use [deleteDirectory()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#deleteDirectory(java.io.File)) to recursively delete directory.

Or you can also use [deleteQuitely()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#deleteQuietly(java.io.File)) to suppress any exceptions while deletion.

Comment: if i added like this          deleteDirectory(f);
 it give me an error and says it is undifined

Comment: you should be doing like this `FileUtils.deleteDirectory(f)` in case static import is not there.

Answer (score 1):

FileUtils does not contain any method named `delete()`, so you should use `deleteDirectory()` instead. Also, please ensure you have imported the correct Java file utility class from [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/). If it is not the case, your need to

- Download Apache Commons IO as a JAR file, link it to the classpath
- Or declare a dependency the Apache Commons IO in your Maven, or other dependency management system.

Here's the code:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class YourClass
{

    public void yourMethod() throws IOException
    {
        File f = new File(directory+"\\OOO");
        if (f.exists())
        {            
            FileUtils.deleteDirectory(f);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
   try {
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File("path");
        //path Example - C:\\myfolder\\foldertodelete
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
```