# Why doesn't sorted(Comparator::reverseOrder) work?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, comparator

The below Stream expression works perfectly fine:

```
Stream<String> s = Stream.of("yellow","blue", "white");
 s.sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
  .forEach(System.out::print);` //yellowwhiteblue
```

Why doesn't the equivalent one with method references compile?

```
s.sorted(Comparator::reverseOrder).forEach(System.out::print);
```

> The type Comparator does not define reverseOrder(String, String) that
>   is applicable here

Comment: Why do you think `Comparator.reverseOrder()` and `Comparator::reverseOrder` are equivalent? Do you think, these were different syntax for the same thing? Were was the sense in that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A method reference is telling Java "treat this method as the implementation of a single-method interface"--that is, the method reference should have the signature `int foo(String,String)` and thus implement `Comparator<String>`.

`Comparator.reverseOrder()` doesn't--it returns *a `Comparator` instance*. Since `sorted` is looking *for* a `Comparator`, it can take the result of the method call, but it can't use that method as the interface implementation.

Comment: I know that here isn't the place of saying thank you, but ohh men, what an answer, simple, concise, clear <3
Read 3 sites and 2 times method reference in the book and was not able to figure out why and how, neither to understand the explanation from the book. 
Sooo a big thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The line of code with method reference **s.sorted(Comparator::reverseOrder)** is telling Java that there is a static method with the signature of a trivial method comparator, it means with two parameters.

The class **Comparator** has only the static method **reverseOrder** without parameters, that's the reason of the compiling error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Stream<String> s=Stream.of("yellow","blue", "white");
        s.sorted(String::compareTo)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

if you still want to use a method reference then the above will work.
This seems to be a common question in OCP Java 8 certification.