# I want to delete a folder,but,i just delete the last one file in the folder

Tags: java, server

I want to delete a folder that has some other files. First, I'll delete all files in the folder, but I just delete the last file, and I cannot delete the folder.

This is my code:

```
private void deleteFiles(File file) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        String [] files = file.list();
        for (int i= 0 ; i < files.length ; i++) {
            deleteFiles(new File(file, files[i]));
        }
    }
    file.delete();
}
```

Comment: You should put more info in your question. What you tried? Show us your code.

Comment: Is this a coding question? I don't see any code...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete directories recursively in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779519/delete-directories-recursively-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
private String deleteFile (File file){
    String info = "";
    if(file.isFile()){
        if(file.delete()){
            info = "remove file success";
        }
    }else if(file.isDirectory()){
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        for(int i = 0;i < files.length;i++){
            this.deleteFile(files[i]);      //recursion
        }
        file.delete();
        info = "remove folder success";
    }else{
        info = "not exist";
    }
    return info;
}
```