# UUID random number generation

Tags: java, uuid

I am using UUID Random number as a primary key of Object when i save object in Database. So this generated UUID number should be unique. This way i got random number.

---

```
final String UUIDUserToken = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```

---

Can this generated number unique for any generated number?

Give me idea.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513573/how-good-is-javas-uuid-randomuuid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may repeat (with very little possibility) ,

Update:

```
try{
  //try inserting
}catch(){
  //SQL constraint fails
  // regenerate new UUID
  //check in DB before inserting
  //insert now, if its unique, else regenerate
}
```

Comment: The probability of getting an repeated UUID is so small, just handle the error when you get it (regenerate the UUID). no need to check the DB every time

Comment: Agreed - just let a database constraint catch it if it ever happens.

Comment: @AviramSegal How will you know its repeated if you don't check the database? Are you saying you should just assume it won't repeat and handle it if it has?

Comment: @PeterLawrey try to insert, if you get an exception because the primary key is not unique make a new one, I see Jigar edited his answer to this method

Answer (score 0):

The generated ID is unique world-wide by definition. 
BTW, why are you generating primary key in java code? Database knows to do this job very well. Just define the field as `AUTO INCREMENT`.

Comment: Providing IDs is e.g. a common technique to improve JPA performance. It also helps when you need unique IDs that do not follow the increment-pattern implemented for auto-generated keys - typical use-case is syncing independent data sources.