# How to parametrize user data in selenium with testng and feed to script

Tags: java, selenium, testng

This question may have been asked but I don't find perfect solution so I am posting here.
I have to Automate a sales force application and have to create new customer data every time I execute a script.
I want to create such that customer name is unique eg: customer 123 etc.

What is best way I can achieve this in Java.
I searched SO and Google but they only give alpha numeric random string and I don't want my customer number to look clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways actually:

1. Delete all previous users with given name at the beginning of script execution, and recreate users with the same names. That way you can reuse their names.
2. Get all users, sort them, see which number was used last, and use the next number.

Both of these options do not really depend on Java features, butmore on logic of names you are creating and maintaining. Two options below generate some integer ID:

3. Use date/time as your number. For example:

   ```
   SimpleDateFormat timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
   String username = "user" + timestamp.format(new Date());
   ```

   This would give you names like `user20181122101458234` unique to millisecond, and also not random.
4. You can also use Java's UUID as your number (see idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171558/unique-number-generation-by-uuid-in-java)):

   ```
   String username = "user" + new BigInteger(UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", ""), 16).toString()
   ```

   This would generate name of type `user[some big number]`, which is quite unique

Comment: @CodingGirl1 You should accept the answer if it helped you. That way the question gets closed as well.