# GUID from two different JVM

Tags: java, unique, guid

I am writing a software where my code runs on two different machines. Will my GUID be still unique across the whole cluster if I have generation logic on multiple JVM.what are chances of collision in my specific use case ?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513573/how-good-is-javas-uuid-randomuuid

Answer (score 1):

If your "GUID" is a [`UUID.randomUUID()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID%28%29) then [the probabilities are quite low](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates). Otherwise, it depends on [how you are generating your GUID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.2.2), but the general principle
behind them is that you have enough random bits so that a collision will be unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case all instances of your distributed system use a common database, then you could create a sequence on that database and use values from that sequence to avoid duplicate IDs.

Answer (score -1):

GLOBALLY unique ID, in this case global means universal.

Every GUID generated is guaranteed to be unique in the universe.  That's the whole purpose of GUIDs.