# UUID.randomUUID collision in Android

Tags: java, android, random, dalvik, udid

I understand that UUID.randomUUID is mostly good: [how good is java's UUID.randomUUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513573/how-good-is-javas-uuid-randomuuid)

Has anyone experienced a problem on Android with UUID.randomUUID. Since Android uses Dalvik VM.

I am not able to reproduce a collision. However, the following code is suspicious (based on reports from my Production) and may result into a collision while running on two different processes (Two apps with the same code and different packages, for example free app vs pro app)?

```
private static final String PREFIX = Long.toString(UUID.randomUUID().getLeastSignificantBits());
```

Any thoughts/experience would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html the least significant digits consist in three fields:

```
 0xC000000000000000 variant
 0x3FFF000000000000 clock_seq
 0x0000FFFFFFFFFFFF node
```

By not taking all the UUID, you are increasing your chances of collisions. How about taking all of it like: `private static final String PREFIX = UUID.randomUUID().toString();`

By that way, you will mitigate your chance of collision.