# Generating a random String using functional principles

Tags: scala

Below is code I wrote to generate a random String (to be used for filename) :

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object FileName{

  var currentFileNameList: ListBuffer[String] = new ListBuffer

  def getFileName(): String = {
    var fileName = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    while (true) {
      if (!currentFileNameList.contains(fileName)) {
        currentFileNameList = currentFileNameList :+ fileName
        return fileName
      } else {
        fileName = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
      }
    }

    throw new RuntimeException("Error - filename not generated")
  }

}
```

The exception `throw new RuntimeException("Error - filename not generated")` should never be thrown but is required as I need to return type String. What is Scala compiler not complaining that im throwing a RuntimeException instead of returning String ?

Is there functional equivalent (no vars) of re-writing above code ?

Comment: Nothing involving randomUUID is going to be pure...

Comment: Nothing being random is going to be functionally pure if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result type of throwing an exception in Scala is [`Nothing`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Nothing) which is the bottom type and thus can be used where (in your case) a `String` is expected.

The chance of UUID collisions is very small (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513573/how-good-is-javas-uuid-randomuuid) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates)), but if you really want to check for file name collisions in a more functional matter, you could use a tail recursive function.

```
def randomFileName(existing: List[String]) : String = {
  val uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString
  if (existing.contains(uuid)) randomFileName(existing)
  else uuid
}
```

Comment: same String could be generated by your method randomFileName as multiple calls to randomFileName will re-initialize List existing, so do not have history of created uuid's.

Comment: If you have created a new file, add the new filename to a list of existing file names and pass that list the next time you call `randomFileName`.