# Duplication of UUID generated in JAVA using AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jsp, uuid

I have been using the code below to generate my UUID and post it in the database :

```
 if (addData.getGeneratedDocId() == null || addData.getGeneratedDocId().equals("")) {
        //addData.setGeneratedDocId(uniqueID);
        addData.setGeneratedDocId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    }
```

The problem is when I deploy my websites in AWS hosting, things start to get worst, I am having duplicate UUID constantly, I have not face any issues while running in the Local Host, any clue? 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513573/how-good-is-javas-uuid-randomuuid) the odds of this happening are exceedingly low.  Can you give us some more information on your code?

Comment: At first, i tried to use <%!String uniqueID = UID.randomUUID().toString();%>

to assign my UUID , when i goes into debug mode , i notice that the UUID does not change , after that i changed it to the code above, any clue? Thanks

i did set my generatedUUID to null everytime after use (Adding into DB)  with this : 
   addData.setGeneratedDocId(null);

Comment: And you're using `java.util.UUID`, correct?  What operating system?  I've generated 10's of millions of UUID's this way and used it as a unique column in a database and never had an issue.  That's what is so strange.

Comment: Yes, i dont know why i am having this issue too, duplicated ids end up messing up other datas in my database.
Sorry i am new to Aws , i have no clue what OS i am using , I am using EC2 Micro for Hosting in Elastic Beanstalk though.

Comment: It was working fine when i am debugging in Netbeans, but error occurs when i am deploying to AWS and testing from it.

Comment: My guess is that you’re using the same `addData` object to repeatedly add data.  Your code, however, only calls `setGeneratedDocId` once.

Comment: I found that problem occurs when i did not Post the form , where i would be getting the previous generated UUID out of nowhere, any solution to let it not save the previous generated UUIDs? Thanks