# Most efficient way to generate 128 char long uuid?

Tags: java

At the moment you can generate a random UUID by using:

```
UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

This results in the following string:

```
94f3c8a3-a161-468f-9844-de92dd90ace7
```

which is 36 char long...too small to be used, for example, as an ID to persist: I'd expect a lot of collisions.

I'd like to generate **at least** 128 char long string...by using the sha512 alg I was able to obtain a longer string but sha512 is meant to be secure, not efficient.
What could I use to obtain longer ids but with low impact on performances?

Comment: Why not get several UUIDs and concatenate?

Comment: "too small to be used, for example, as an ID to persist." really? You'd expect a lot of collisions? Then you expect wrong.

Comment: Generate 4 UUIDs and concatenate. Also we use UUIDs as primary keys with no issue.

Comment: Just for helpful reading check out [how good is java's UUID.randomUUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513573/how-good-is-javas-uuid-randomuuid)

Comment: UUIDs with 16 hexadecimal characters offer approx. 2.2E43 choises. Thats a **lot** of possibilities. So collisions are very unlikely

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on the misunderstanding of the author that UUID is somehow collision prone.

Comment: If you find that sha512'ing a 128bit UUID is a theoretically acceptable answer, you can just zero pad your UUID until it's the size you want. It'll be equally collision resistant but much faster.

Comment: A UUID is by definition 128 **bits**, which is represented by 36 characters in that output. If you want something longer, it is **not an UUID**. In which case you are maybe searching for a way to generate a string of 128 characters.

Comment: The author of this Question has misunderstood [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)s and has misunderstood how large a range of numbers is 128-bits (or 122-bits). As for largeness, read [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/bonwick/128-bit-storage:-are-you-high) or [this](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=372381). While a properly-produced Version 4 UUID is good enough for most purposes, if you want to eliminate any practical possibility of a collision, use Version 1. You can obtain those from Java libraries, native code, or from a database or web service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement:

> which is 36 char long...too small to be used

is most likely incorrect unless you are doing cryptography. This 36 characters are encoding 128 bit value as per [Universally unique identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). Assuming UUID version 4 returned by `UUID.randomUUID()` method, to quote the wiki further:

> As in other UUIDs, four bits
>   are used to indicate version 4, and 2 or 3 bits to indicate the
>   variant (10 or 110 for variants 1 and 2, respectively). Thus, for
>   variant 1 (that is, most UUIDs) a random version 4 UUID will have 6
>   predetermined variant and version bits, leaving 122 bits for the
>   randomly-generated part, for a total of 2^122, or 5.3x10^36 (5.3
>   undecillion) possible version 4 variant 1 UUIDs.

You are extremely unlikely to experience any collisions ever in your code. They can happen but:

> Thus, for there to be a one in a billion chance of duplication, 103
>   trillion version 4 UUIDs must be generated.

Comment: I would say “You are *extremely* unlikely to experience any collisions ever in your code.” Furthermore, to effectively eliminate any possibility of collision, use time-and-space-based Version 1 values rather than random-based Version 4.

Comment: Add the extremely part, it makes it clearer, thanks.