# How to generate CorrelationID from Tibco BW5?

Tags: guid, tibco, tibco-ems, tibco-business-works

I am using "Queue Sender" pattern for sending JMS message from Tibco BW5.
I set ReplayTo and correlationID into "Sender" and read response from "Get JMS Queue Message" using CorrelationID

[image]

[image]

[image]

please see https://www.rubix.nl/blogs/jms-request-response-patterns-tibco-businessworks-and-ems for mode detail "Queue Sender" pattern explanation.

I am using

```
concat($_processContext/ns11:ProcessContext/ProcessId, tib:timestamp())
```

for generating CorrelationID that I think may be not unique enough.
What is the best practice for generating CorrelationID from TibcoBW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `uuid()` function. It generates an **Universally Unique IDentifier (UUID)**

[image: guid generation]

Comment: standard java UUID.randomUUID() should work. We finally decide to use UUID.randomUUID(). Interesting topic here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513573/how-good-is-javas-uuid-randomuuid  they suggest to use UuidUtil.getTimeBasedUuid  from log4j 2 for more uniqueness