# method to generating random UUID using Java

Tags: java, uuid

I have a task to generate a unique string, the first thought which came to my mind was to use
Java's UUID generator with additional improvements. And so my way of generating a random string
looks something like this

```
public static String generateRandomString() {
    return "TEST" + 
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSSSSS")
                    .format(LocalDateTime.now()) + UUID.randomUUID()
            .toString().replace("-", "");
}
```

would this method generating a random string would be sufficient to achieve uniqueness having in
mind that I need to generate 10 000 000 of them on a daily basis for the next 20 years. Also,
this piece of code will be spinning on different JVM and potentially on different servers.

Comment: Why not just using `UUID.randomUUID()` alone?

Comment: To get/preserve an information on when approximately the string was generated.

Comment: Just as an aside, all of the date/time formatting just gives the same uniqueness as using System.currentTimeMillis()

Answer (score 3):

`UUID.randomUUID()` generates a type-4 UUID.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions):

> Thus, the probability to find a duplicate within 103 trillion version-4 UUIDs is one in a billion.

More [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513573/how-good-is-javas-uuid-randomuuid).

Answer (score 2):

Just do the maths:

```
10000000*365*20 =                             73000000000
2^128           = 340282366920938463463374607431768211456
```

I'd say you can use it after comparing these numbers.

EDIT: I just saw a few other answers, definitely check if `UUID.randomUUID()` uses the full 128 bits or only some.

Comment: How this number 2^128 would be impacted knowing that multiple JVM could generate
a random string using this very same method?

Comment: A version 4 UUID returned by `UUID.randomUUID()` has 122 random bits. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)

Comment: @miroana Nothing to worry about, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155008/how-unique-is-uuid