# GWT - RPC - get servlet absolute path to make dir

Tags: gwt, file-io, rpc

I tried to read a file with my "RemoteServiceServlet" but the thing is

- I want to create a dir which path is related to servlet like

> absolute_servlet_path/myPackage/

But the problem is...

code like

```
ServletContext servletContext = this.getServletContext();
String pathContext = servletContext.getRealPath("");
```

... gives not **"C:/..."** but **"/"** only so the code cannot be used with java.io.File object.

So my question is how can I use java.io.File with RemoteServiceServlet ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK... I had to keep digging...

Still I was looking for a way of servlet relative path but an absolute one; and now again I tried to use the context but this time I modified my code in this direction...

```
ServletContext servletContext = this.getServletContext();
String pathContext = servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/");
```

... and it worked for my Tomcat :)

I hope it saves one's day

Thanks

Comment: I hope you understand that this directory is where your WAR file is deployed. When you redeploy your application anything you put in there will most likely be erased.

Comment: Sure :) I needed it just for my web app temp files only. I wasn't use user.home etc but to have a related path. So it is OK as for me :)

Comment: A little unconventional. Perhaps you want to have a look at more standard ways to create temp files, discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617414/create-a-temporary-directory-in-java

Comment: +1 @Strelok for your additional commenting me. Thank you but I really found the thing I wanted for my test app :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand how servlets work. A "servlet" is just a class configured via the web.xml file to process requests on a given path at a URL. It's in now way related to the file system at all.

Why would you want to create a folder relative to your servlet's URL? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am just trying to get the same effect as desktop app does. It is the default path like "." as for the File object. So not to use user.home or something :)