# Junit Test case for void method which creates a file

Tags: java, file-io, junit4

I have Java program which fetches HTML from a website. It displays the content on console and then saves it to a file named `web_content.txt`. How do I write a test case for this?

My Program is:

```
public class UrlDown {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      UrlDown down = new UrlDown();
      File f = new File("web_content.txt");
      String loc = "http://www.google.com";
      down.saveUrlToFile(f, loc);

   }

   public void saveUrlToFile(File saveFile, String location) {
      URL url;
      try {
         url = new URL(location);
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
               url.openStream()));
         BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(saveFile));

         char[] cbuf = new char[255];
         StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
         while ((in.read(cbuf)) != -1) {
            out.write(cbuf);
            builder.append(cbuf);
         }
         String downloaded = builder.toString();
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println(downloaded);
         in.close();
         out.close();

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Whats thet question? There's nothing about Junit in the code you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Don't [reinvent the square wheel](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/dont-reinvent-the-wheel-unless-you-plan-on-learning-more-about-wheels.html). Just use some lib.

For example FileUtils from apache-commons - [http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile(java.net.URL, java.io.File)](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile%28java.net.URL,%20java.io.File%29)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Java 7, you can use the [Files.copy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) method to save the content of a `InputStream`to a file.

To verify that this is working you can use the [TemporaryFolder](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html) from jUnit to verify that you get the location correct, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6185359/303598

Answer (score 0):

Have your unit test setup a mock http server (google will give you plenty of info). Pass in a url and check the file contains the expected content