# I am unable to create temporary file

Tags: java

I am trying to create a temporary files using java.But when i run my codes it shows the following error.

```
number.java:7: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Path
location: class number
    Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile(null, ".txt");
    ^
number.java:7: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method createTempFile(<nulltype>,java.lang.String)
location: class Files
    Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile(null, ".txt");
                         ^
2 errors
```

and here's the code
and when i import java.io.file;.then it show error package does not exist

```
import java.io.*;


public class number{
public static void main(String args[])
{try {
    Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile(null, ".txt");
    System.out.format("The temporary file" +
        " has been created: %s%n", tempFile);
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
}
}}
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617414/create-a-temporary-directory-in-java

Comment: in which package `Files` comes? It should have been `File` I guess.

Comment: After upgrading to SE7 the error is   Desktop\Jdbc\number.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
    Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile(temp, ".txt");
                                         ^
  symbol:   variable temp
  location: class number
1 error

Answer (score 1):

`Files.createTempFile(null, ".txt");` 1st parameter cant be null, it can be any prefix (basically to identify your temp file among lots of other). pass it some non null values.

```
Files.createTempFile("myfile", ".txt");
```

Also, correct import as below

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;
```

Comment: what should i pass in place of null

Comment: After changing this number.java:7: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Path
location: class number
    Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile(temp, ".txt");
    ^
number.java:7: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable temp
location: class number
    Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile(temp, ".txt");
                                         ^
2 errors

Comment: when i import java.io.file.Files error is package java.io.file does not exist

Comment: yes, bcz its under java.nio.file, not java.io.file

Comment: java.io.file also exist http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-tips/io/10file/05file.shtml

Comment: @Gaurav yes, but you are mixing it up. Path & Files are in java7. Better decide what you wanna use. Under java 7 or below..... check the answer to correct the imports

Answer (score 0):

The Path class, introduced in the Java SE 7 release, is one of the primary entrypoints of the java.nio.file package. If your application uses file I/O, you will want to learn about the powerful features of this class.
See this for more info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathClass.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html

Comment: To use path which package should i import

Comment: Package java.nio.file

Comment: I think same should be supported by java.io.file

Comment: it introduced in Java SE 7 release see my links you can get full info

Comment: but java.io.file is also supported in 5.0

Comment: Yeah but class Path in in nio only

Comment: I was using SE6 now i upgrade to SE7 but same problem arise

Comment: did you import java.nio.file.*;

Comment: yes I import these 2  import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

Comment: Check the class path set correctly in your system.

Comment: ya its OK problem in program is having problem in temp variable

Comment: So you can check my answer as correct right?

Comment: My problem is not yet solved what are the argument for createTempFile();