# Where to store temporary files in a Java web application?

Tags: java, web-applications, spring-mvc

I'm developing a java/spring-mvc web app that using a scheduling system generate csv files to send via e mail.

My first idea was to generate these files locally in server and then send them to recipients, but now I have a doubt. Where to store temp files?

I will deploy my application as a war, so I know there could be problems.

Is it a bad idea to create a temporary directory in my WEB-INF directory? An alternative could be to serialize these files and store them in a database table.

What's your suggestion? any best practice?

Answer (score 8):

I would left it on jvm, i.e. use `java.io.tmpdir` system property. Create a directory in tmp dir (`new File(system.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")).mkdir()`) or just a file in the tmp directory (`File.createTempFile("name", ".csv")`).
For application running on Tomcat, the tmp dir is `<catalina_home_directory>/temp`.

Answer (score 1):

[How to create a temporary directory/folder in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617414/create-a-temporary-directory-in-java) - also on how to do this the best way in Java 7.

It really sounds like simple temporary files are exactly what you need - and you don't really need to worry about where to store them, Java does that for you. Why would you store them in a DB if you'd only need them temporarily? Databases are for persistent storage you care about. And the hassle of serializing, neh...