# Best practice to save temp files on tomcat?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, tomcat, temp

I need to demo a xml based data interchange system. It is demoed offline on a trusted computer at school. The application will get database later but just for this presentation I only need to show the layout, opening and saving of xml-files and how the table gets data from the xml.

So, what would be the best location to let the web app create the xml files temporarily so I can showcase this app? I'm using Eclipse and Tomcat.

As mentioned, **security is not an issue at all**, since this version is NOT going to be online. Also, it's **ok if the files get erased each time the application is run.**

They need to exist only for the duration of the presentation where the application is run once. So, I'm clueless what would be the best location and how to get the path to such location not depending on the computer used.

Thank you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617414/create-a-temporary-directory-in-java

Comment: If it's okay that the files get erased, and presumably as it's a demo there won't be a lot of them, why not just keep them in memory in a map or something similar?

Comment: You can use property `java.io.tmpdir` to get the tmp location and save your files there.

Comment: how about tomcat/temp as pointed to by java.io.tmpdir

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the property `java.io.tmpdir` to get the `tomcat` temp folder and save your files there. That will be a good place to temporarily keep them in. So you can define it as follows:

```
public static final String TMP_DIR = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")
```

Answer (score 9):

Either use the property `java.io.tmpdir` as indicated or use the servlet context attribute `javax.servlet.context.tempdir` defined in the specification. For tomcat that attribute can be changed by the workDir attribute on the context.

You can use that attribute by a call to `servletContext.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir")`

[See tomcat documentation for detail.](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Standard_Implementation)

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but if there is for creating temp file why not use  `File.createTempFile` function?

Example:

```
File temp = File.createTempFile("real",".howto");
temp.deleteOnExit();
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use this method to get `temp` file location according to your Operating System

```
public static String getSystemFileLocation()
{
    File tmpFile = null;
    String fileLocation="/tmp/";
    if (System.getProperty("os.name").toUpperCase().indexOf("WINDOWS") == 0) {
        tmpFile=new File("c:\\temp");
        if(tmpFile.exists()) {
            fileLocation="c:\\temp\\";
        }
        else {
            tmpFile.mkdir();
            fileLocation="c:\\temp\\";
        }
    }
    else if (System.getProperty("os.name").toUpperCase().indexOf("WINDOWS") == -1) {
        fileLocation="/tmp/";   
    }
    return fileLocation;
}
```

Comment: Negative and dangerous way...

Comment: This questions is talks about temp folder in tomcat but your code is to get temp folder in os level