# Vaadin and Netbeans 8.2 - need to create a folder within the web app

Tags: java, netbeans, vaadin

I need to upload a csv file and read the file from the Vaadin web application (using tomcat).  i would like to create a folder and upload the file and read the file from that folder.  i thought i could go into netbeans and create a folder under the web pages->WEB-INF but when i generate the WAR file and deploy it to the tomcat server, the folder i created from Netbeans is gone.  why is it gone?  How can i create the folder within the ide and also see it from the tomcat file structure?

TIA,

Thomas

Comment: Usually you create the file in the temp folder and use it from there. Somthing like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775620/best-practice-to-save-temp-files-on-tomcat

Comment: Funny thing was i tested the project in both tomcat 7 (win) and tomcat 8 (CENTOS).  Win server app uploaded it to the catalina temp dir.   CENTOS uploaded to the folder i manually created (which is what I wanted)... i am wondering if it had to do with the tomcat version...

Comment: Perhaps more about the rights the tomcat has on different systems?