# Is there a "Standard" path where you can create a "working folder"?

Tags: java, path

I'm writing a Java program that has to create a folder on the disk, store some file in it, and when the program is terminated, the folder is deleted:

The problem is that, when my program is opened on a random pc, how should it know where to store files?

I saw a lot of installers that already suggest you a path (like "Program Files", "Roaming" etc), how can I make my program know these paths?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard path is

```
System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
```

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()

you might use it together with

```
File.createTempFile();
```

as suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/617438/7023245

Comment: _System.getProperty("user.temp")_ returns null to me...?

Comment: @Dea5 I failed to look up the correct key in the API. I corrected the answer.