# how to create in-memory folder in java

Tags: java, file, filesystems, directory

how to create in-memory folder in java.
I have a requirement of creating a folder in-memory and then write files in it. Is it possible? If yes how?

Comment: Do you mean like a "virtual drive"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure about the term "in-memory folder" but I would guess you mean temporary files and directories?

If that is what you are looking for then this question should help you:
[How to create a temporary directory/folder in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617414/how-to-create-a-temporary-directory-folder-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

In plain java (before java 7) i do not think is possible, however you could use the [apache common vfs library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/) which has a RAM file system type.
In java 7 and above (as suggested by @ervin-szilagyi) you could implement your own [FileSystemProvider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileSystemProvider.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually you can in Java 7 and above: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileSystemProvider.html

Comment: many thanx Ervin, i didn't knew that :)