# How to reference an executable resource file

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I am working on a Maven project and I would like to access the `resources` folder that contains an executable: `geckodriver.exe`

Path: `src/main/resources/geckodriver/`

I know after packaging, the is copied in `target`. Therefore, the file should be accessible via `classpath`. Then I should be able to access the file by writing this: `MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("geckodriver/geckodriver.exe")`.

An exception is displayed when I run the project: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist`

Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: You can't use `getResource` if you packaged to a jar file and runs from that, because the file is inside the jar file, and not on the file system. Is that what you did?

Comment: The package is a `jar`. The idea is to have an executable jar that contains all the files necessary to run.

Comment: You need to copy the resource(s) to some location on the harddisk, e.g. to a temporary directory: [How to create a temporary directory/folder in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/617414/5221149). Remember to clean up (delete the folder and files) when done. Copy should use [`getResourceAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) and [`Files.copy(InputStream in, Path target)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-)

Comment: @Andreas ^^^That^^^ was in short what OP needs to do exactly.