# How to provide a classpath resource to a function accepting a File parameter?

Tags: java, classpath

I am working with an external API which provides the following function:

```
public void process(File file) {
}
```

In my case, the file to be provided is in a JAR in the classpath. Is there a way to provide a `File` representing this file to `process(File)`?

I tried the following:

```
new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("my-file.txt").toURI()))
```

This gives the error: `URI is not hierarchical`.

I did some researching and understood that files on the classpath should not be considered as a regular file, but as a resource. This makes me believe that there is no easy way to construct a `File` for that resource.

Should I copy the resource to a temporary file first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you'd fix the API, which is definitively broken. Otherwise, the only reliable way to get a `File` is to copy to a temporary one. You'll probably want to use [`Files.createTempDirectory`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617414/how-to-create-a-temporary-directory-folder-in-java) and then something like Apache Commons IO [IOUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) to copy the contents.

Comment: Thank you very much. So this means that I can only work with the API by creating a copy first?

Comment: If this API requires an actual `File` object, then yes. This is _exactly_ why a `process` method should be using a `Reader` or `InputStream` instead.

Comment: Got it! I'll ask the API maintainer to add such method and in the meantime I'll work around it by creating a temporary file, in a temporary directory as you said.

Comment: For a useful example, take a look at the various `readValue` signatures available in Jackson: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html

Comment: Those are useful. Appreciate the information!

Comment: It would be useful if Guava or some other library has a convenient utility function for this :). I could work with IOUtilis as you said, but then I still have to create the directory, open and close an OutputStream and such. That said, it's better than having to do everything by hand.