# how can I create a temporary folder in java 6?

Tags: java, temporary-directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a temporary directory in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617414/create-a-temporary-directory-in-java)

Duplicate: [stackoverflow.com/questions/375910](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375910)

Is there a way of creating a temporary folder in java ? I know of File's static method createTempFile, but this will only give me a temporary file.

Comment: Why isn't this question flagged as duplicate?  Brian Agnew has posted the relevant links.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I've never seen a good solution for this, but this is how I've done it.

```
File temp = File.createTempFile("folder-name","");
temp.delete();
temp.mkdir();
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach. I didn't think about it this way.

Answer (score 8):

Any reason you can't use the directory defined by the java.io.tmpdir property?

ie

```
String dirName = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
```

Comment: 'Temporary file' from createTempFile is automatically deleted when JVM exits. I think OP is asking for this kind of directory, so using existing tmpdir directory won't make it. (I needed something similar for writing unit tests, and used createTempFile+delete+mkdir and created only 'temporary' files within this directory -- JVM can then do the cleanup, if I remember correctly)

Comment: Ok, it's not deleted automatically .. you need to ask JVM first to do so (by deleteOnExit)

Comment: Just as a side note: you could easily add 'destruction on JVM exit' yourself by registering a shutdown hook.

Answer (score 5):

I would check out [this past question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617414/create-a-temporary-directory-in-java) for a solution. Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375910/creating-a-temp-dir-in-java)!

Answer (score 4):

I write my own utility classes for creating temporary directories and for disposing them when they are not anymore needed. For example [like this](http://code.google.com/p/darkstar-contrib/source/browse/trunk/darkstar-integration-test/src/main/java/net/orfjackal/darkstar/integration/util/TempDirectory.java).